# ZLib.lib(d000062.o) : warning LNK4078: multiple '.text' sections found with different attributes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, zlib, linker-warning

I downloaded zlib from their website and I have the link warning from the title. I also compiled zlib and still have same warning. Do you know how may I fix this? I don't like warning of any kind in my projects:)

I use Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the compiler used to generate the .lib import for the DLL [isn't entirely compatible](http://mail.madler.net/pipermail/zlib-devel_madler.net/2010-August/002428.html) with Visual Studio:

> I thought MinGW can be a one-stop shop
>   that'll do what's needed, and we won't
>   need anymore the awkward two-tool
>   combination that we used to use around
>   zlib-1.2.3. It seems we need another,
>   even more awkward two-tool combination
>   now.

Cosmin Truta [built](http://cosmin.users.sourceforge.net/testing/zlib125-dll-patch1.zip) a new version using Visual studio.  It should fix the warnings.

Comment: Your links are broken now. However the newer zlib versions at zlib.net don't have this problem.